# android read xml file in the root directory

Tags: android, xml, import

can not Read the file。
I found that after using debug debugging is str = parser.nextText (); this step exception. I ask my xml file format there is something wrong？

```java
package com.example.sqltest;


import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

import com.example.sqltest.dao.person;
import com.example.sqltest.dao.personDao2;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private TextView tv ;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.linerayoutmain);

        personDao2 pd = new personDao2(this);
        long number = 10000 ;
        Random random = new Random();
        for (int i = 0 ; i <50;i++){
            pd.add("wengwenewn"+i, Long.toString(number+random.nextInt(5000)));
        }
        List<person> persons = pd.findall();      
    }        
}
```

this is my  `the weather.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<info>
<city>"china"</city>
</info>
```

the weather.xml palced         D:\eclipse workspce\testReadXML\src\weather.xml

my logcat show as :.

```java
03-16 09:56:32.521: E/memtrack(1867): Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
03-16 09:56:32.521: E/android.os.Debug(1867): failed to load memtrack module: -2
03-16 09:56:33.121: E/memtrack(1877): Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
03-16 09:56:33.121: E/android.os.Debug(1877): failed to load memtrack module: -2
```

Comment: Can you please explain, what exactly is your problem? I am not able to understand it.

Comment: The code you show does not contain the statement that you claim throws an exception. The xml file you show is not referenced anywhere in the code you show. Please show the stacktrace too.

Comment: Your question is incomplete, however your likely problem is in mistakenly thinking that an xml file in your source will be available on the device.  If you want something like that, put your xml file in the assets/ folder and access it using the assets API, not the File API.